# If f(n) = O(g(n)), g(n) = O(h(n)), is h(n) = Ω(f(n)) true?

Tags: asymptotics, runtime-analysis, big-o-notation

I have $f(n) = O(g(n))$ and $g(n) = O(h(n))$.

Is $h(n) = \Omega(f(n))$ true, and if so, what constants would make it true?

I was thinking that since $f(n) = O(g(n))$ and $g(n) = O(h(n))$ are true, then $f(n) = O(h(n))$.

I can state $h(n) = \Omega(O(h(n)))$ but I don't know what to do from here. Any pointers?

Comment: Use that if $f(x) = O(g(x))$, then $g(x) = \Omega(f(x))$.

Comment: so if $g(x) = \Omega(f(x))$, then $h(x) = g(x)$? @vonbrand

Comment: By the way, $\Omega(O(h))$ is not well-defined.

Answer (score 2):

For big-$O$ holds property, sometimes called transitivity of big-$O$:
$$f\in O(g) \land g \in O(h) \Rightarrow f \in O(h)$$
last of course means, also, $h \in \Omega(f)$: because if we have $f(n)\leqslant C \cdot h(n)$, then this is same with $h(n) \geqslant \frac{1}{C}\cdot f(n)$.

Proof of transitivity can be based on simple note, the $f\in O(g) \Rightarrow O(f) \subset O(g)$ and then used transitivity of subsets.

Comment: Correct for the Knuth definition of $\Omega$. But it may be useful to also mention that under the Hardy-Littlewood definition of $\Omega$, the implication $f \in O(h) \Leftrightarrow g \in \Omega(f)$ may not hold. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#The_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_definition